# Why does \rm work but rm doesn't?

Tags: unix, shell

Usually whenever I remove directories, "rm -rf " works. But sometimes I get this response:

"rm: examine files in directory / (yes/no)?"

Then I try "\rm -rf ", and that works. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: If it asks you whether to examine the files in '/', do you say 'yes' or 'no'?  And does the machine continue to work afterwards?  Be very careful about deleting everything under root when running as root; the machine keeps going for a surprisingly long time, but there comes a point at which you have to reboot - off a CD or something similar.

Answer (score 10):

Someone, either your system administrator or your linux distribution (you didn't specify what form of unix you are using) has aliased `rm` to `rm -i`. Take a look at what `man rm` says:

> -i      Request confirmation before attempting to remove each file,
>            regardless of the file's permissions, or whether or not the
>            standard input device is a terminal.  The -i option overrides
>            any previous -f options.

You can see the actual binding of any command with the `which` command: `which rm` will say something like:

> rm: mapped to rm -i

To execute the *real* rm, type `\rm`, as you have already discovered.

Comment: +1 At least someone explains what that `-i` actually means.

Answer (score 5):

your rm command is alias, most likely `rm -i`.

check your shell alias.

Answer (score 2):

Also consider calling it as: `yes | rm -rf`

Answer (score 2):

Most of the new linux distro are making safy aliases

usually the `rm` command is aliased to `rm -i`.

You can remove that alias if you don't need it by doing `rm='rm'`, also to make it automatic take a look at bash configuration files.

Good luck